# Using SQL's DISTINCT function to remove unwanted duplicates with a custom delimiter?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I am trying to use GROUP_CONCAT with a custom delimiter which is working:

```
private val mainQuery = "SELECT re.ENTRY_ID, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(re._ID, '§') AS read_id, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(re.READING_ELEMENT, '§') AS read_element, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(re.FURIGANA_BOTTOM, '§') AS furigana_bottom, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(re.FURIGANA_TOP, '§') AS furigana_top, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(re.NO_KANJI, '§') AS no_kanji, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(re.READING_COMMONNESS, '§') AS read_commonness, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(re.READING_RELATION, '§') AS read_rel, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(se.POS, '§') AS pos, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(se.GLOSS, '§') AS gloss, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(se.FIELD, '§') AS field, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(se.DIALECT, '§') AS dialect, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(se.INFORMATION, '§') AS info " +
            "FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element AS re " +
            "JOIN Jmdict_Sense_Element AS se ON re.ENTRY_ID = se.ENTRY_ID " +
            "JOIN Jmdict_Kanji_Element AS ke ON re.ENTRY_ID = ke.ENTRY_ID "

    private val kanjiQuery = mainQuery +
            "WHERE ke.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Kanji_Element WHERE KANJI_ELEMENT LIKE ?) " +
            "GROUP BY re.ENTRY_ID " +
            "ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ke.KANJI_ELEMENT = ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), " +
            "(CASE WHEN ke.KANJI_ELEMENT LIKE ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), " +
            "(CASE WHEN se.GLOSS = ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), " +
            "(CASE WHEN se.GLOSS LIKE ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), re.READING_ELEMENT"

    private val kanaAndEnglishQuery =  mainQuery +
            "WHERE re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element WHERE READING_ELEMENT LIKE ?) " +
            "OR re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Sense_Element WHERE GLOSS LIKE ?) " +
            "GROUP BY re.ENTRY_ID " +
            "ORDER BY (CASE WHEN re.READING_ELEMENT = ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), " +
            "(CASE WHEN re.READING_ELEMENT LIKE ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), " +
            "(CASE WHEN se.GLOSS = ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), " +
            "(CASE WHEN se.GLOSS LIKE ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), re.READING_ELEMENT"
```

However, as soon as I try to add `DISTINCT`: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT re.READING_ELEMENT, '§') AS read_element`, it no longer works: `DISTINCT aggregates must have exactly one argument`.
I am trying to remove the duplicates found. (Even though they aren't in the database... if there is
something that is in the query that is causing this please answer with that because that would also solve the problem)

Comment: Given that you have ready access to application code, I would be tempted to solve the entirety of this problem there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not support the *separator* argument if you use `DISTINCT` inside `GROUP_CONCAT()` (maybe it's a bug).
What you can do is:

```
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT re.READING_ELEMENT), ',', '§')
```

to replace all the commas (default delimiter) with the delimiter of your choice.
If the column contains commas, then a (dirty) solution is to replace them with a character that you know does not exist, say `'*'`:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT REPLACE(re.READING_ELEMENT, ',', '*')), ',', '§'), '*', ',')
```

Comment: the thing is is that most of my cells contain commas, so this won't work I don't think

Answer (score 0):

get the distinct() first using a subquery, before performing `group_concat()`. Since we will be getting distinct on `re.READING_ELEMENT`, will be grouping by this column instead.

```
private val mainQuery = "SELECT re.ENTRY_ID, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(t1._ID, '§') AS read_id, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(t1.READING_ELEMENT, '§') AS read_element, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(t1.FURIGANA_BOTTOM, '§') AS furigana_bottom, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(t1.FURIGANA_TOP, '§') AS furigana_top, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(t1.NO_KANJI, '§') AS no_kanji, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(t1.READING_COMMONNESS, '§') AS read_commonness, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(t1.READING_RELATION, '§') AS read_rel, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(t1.POS, '§') AS pos, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(t1.GLOSS, '§') AS gloss, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(t1.FIELD, '§') AS field, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(t1.DIALECT, '§') AS dialect, " +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(t1.INFORMATION, '§') AS info FROM " +
            "(SELECT re._ID, re.READING_ELEMENT, re.FURIGANA_BOTTOM, re.FURIGANA_TOP, re.NO_KANJI " +
            ", re.READING_COMMONNESS, re.READING_RELATION, se.POS, se.GLOSS, se.FIELD, se.DIALECT, se.INFORMATION " +
            "FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element AS re " +
            "JOIN Jmdict_Sense_Element AS se ON re.ENTRY_ID = se.ENTRY_ID " +
            "JOIN Jmdict_Kanji_Element AS ke ON re.ENTRY_ID = ke.ENTRY_ID"

private val kanjiQuery = mainQuery +
            " WHERE ke.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Kanji_Element WHERE KANJI_ELEMENT LIKE ?) GROUP BY(re.READING_ELEMENT) ) t1" +
            "GROUP BY t1.ENTRY_ID " +
            "ORDER BY (CASE WHEN t1.KANJI_ELEMENT = ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), " +
            "(CASE WHEN t1.KANJI_ELEMENT LIKE ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), " +
            "(CASE WHEN t1.GLOSS = ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), " +
            "(CASE WHEN t1.GLOSS LIKE ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), t1.READING_ELEMENT"

private val kanaAndEnglishQuery =  mainQuery +
            " WHERE re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element WHERE READING_ELEMENT LIKE ?) " +
            "OR re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Sense_Element WHERE GLOSS LIKE ?) GROUP BY(re.READING_ELEMENT)) t1" +
            "GROUP BY t1.ENTRY_ID" +
            "ORDER BY (CASE WHEN t1.READING_ELEMENT = ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), " +
            "(CASE WHEN t1.READING_ELEMENT LIKE ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), " +
            "(CASE WHEN t1.GLOSS = ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), " +
            "(CASE WHEN t1.GLOSS LIKE ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), t1.READING_ELEMENT"
```

Comment: @AdenDiamond, try again

Comment: I did not get the error before (without using distinct), but I will try to find the issue

Comment: you need to re enter those columms again `select distinct re._ID....... `

Comment: so your answer's code is not working? exactly what do you mean by re-entering the columns

Comment: @AdenDiamond, anywayd I have added the columns for you. you may try now

Comment: now I am getting `near "AS": syntax error` Also didn't get this before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203220/discussion-between--and-aden-diamond).

Comment: Note that distinct() is not a thing